# How to include text to speech functionality in my code?

Tags: c#, javascript, text-to-speech

If I have an HTML and JS page, and I want to add text to speech or even speech to text to it what is the best way? I already have code for speech to text in C# but am not sure how to link them together!

I saw a [text-to-speech google chrome extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/beta/tts.html). How can I include it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  [SAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(v=vs.85).aspx) for converting text to speech ...